# Get All row value of specfic columns on datatable

Tags: c#, ajax, datatables, webmethod

I facing issue how we can get a all row value of specific columns from datatable  in a single variable using ajax

I am trying various method to get different row data some thing like this :

```
var table = $('#gradefourpersondata').DataTable();
            var Uid = table.row(0).data();
```

Comment: Show us your problem as a [mre] - including a sample of data. Then you can describe (a) what data your existing code is selecting; (b) what data you want to select, instead. Without this extra information, we can only guess at the answer.

Comment: Maybe the answer is as simple as `var Uid = table.column(0).data().toArray();` - but that is a guess. See [ask] for more guidance.